# Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line

Tags: java, json

I have seen the same questions over stackoverflow, which tells about extra comma and spaces in Json. But it did nt helped me.

I am having a json of this format with POJO

```
 {"binary":[
    {
    "attributeIndex": 4,
    "attributeValue": "no",
    "binaryValue": "1,0"
  },
  {
    "attributeIndex": 4,
    "attributeValue": "yes",
    "binaryValue": "0,1"
  }
]}
```

POJO

```
public class BinPojo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    int attributeIndex;
    String attributeValue;
    String binaryValue;
and

public class BinaryPojo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    JSONArray binary;
```

I am trying to get  attributeIndex,attributeValue,binaryValue values
But I am getting this error

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 65
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:818)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
```

at

```
BinPojo getData = gson.fromJson(meta.get(j).toString(), BinPojo.class);
```

My code:

```
JSONArray meta = new JSONArray();
//file read
String setupData = bf.readLine();
BinaryPojo d = gson.fromJson(setupData, BinaryPojo.class);
meta = d.getBinary();

 //JSONArray meta which holds the JSON data
for (int j = 0; j < meta.size(); j++) {
    BinPojo getData = gson.fromJson(meta.get(j).toString(), BinPojo.class);
    System.out.println("gson"+gson.toJson(getData));
    int attrIndex = getData.getAttributeIndex();
    System.out.println("attrIndex: "+attrIndex);
    String attrVal = getData.getAttributeValue();               
}
```

What could be the reason. It is telling that my JSON is bad.how can I debug this.

**EDIT**

Once I print this:

```
System.out.println("meta: "+meta.get(j).toString());
```

My result is

> meta: {attributeIndex=0.0, attributeValue=Middleaged,
>   binaryValue=1,0,0}

and

```
for (int j = 0; j < meta.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println("meta: "+meta.get(j).toString());
    BinPojo getData = null ;
    try{
        getData = gson.fromJson(meta.get(j).toString(), BinPojo.class);
    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("gson "+gson.toJson(getData));
    int attrIndex = getData.getAttributeIndex();
    System.out.println("attrIndex: "+attrIndex);
    String attrVal = getData.getAttributeValue();           
    }
```

getData is returning null.

```
gson null
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Well, you want to see what's in `meta.get(j).toString()`. So, maybe store that in a variable in a separate line before parsing it, put a `try`/`catch` around the `gson.fromJson()` call, and if it throws an exception, print out that exact string as part of the error message. Or just stop it in a debugger: as long as you've stored that string in a variable, it'll be there for you to examine.

Comment: You can see it is expecting `:` and you are passing `=` using your meta.get(j).toString()

Comment: It seems the meta.get(j).toString()  provide wrong result, and don't give you the Json String. What is your meta class ?

Comment: @NamanGala: I did nt get you

Comment: @Vyncent: meta is not a class but a JSONARRAY which holds the json data

Comment: Can i see the declaration of the meta variable and how it's filled ?

Comment: sure. The json data is stored to JSONARRAY of a POJO class. Will include that too

Comment: Why don't you simply do `JsonArray meta = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(new File("file")), JsonArray.class);`? Also its working fine for me (I instantiated the `JsonArray` like I mentionned). And there is no need for the `toString` call, `BinPojo getData = gson.fromJson(meta.get(j), BinPojo.class);` should work as expected.

Comment: more question from me, you setup meta (JSONArray) with BinaryPojo,  BinaryPojo d = gson.fromJson(setupData, BinaryPojo.class);
    meta = d.getBinary();
So what is BinaryPojo

Comment: What libraries are the `JSONArray` class and whatever `gson`'s class is from? Could you cut the code down to make a simpler example that still causes your error.

Comment: @Vyncent: BinaryPojo is one of my POJO class which I mentioned above

Comment: Ok, so instead of toString try getAsString()
meta.get(j).toString() become
meta.get(j).getAsString()

Comment: @AlexisC. If we remove toString, error will be shown to cast them to String.

Comment: @AndrewJanke: JSONArray: org.json.simple.JSONArray; and gson of com.google.gson.Gson;

Comment: @Vyncent: when changed to meta.get(j).getAsString()  shows error to cast to toString()

Comment: That's the problem: You're using JSON-simple, and everyone (including your code) is assuming that it follows the signature of "JSON for Java".

Comment: @SreeVeni Why you mix 2 different Json library? Use JsonArray from Gson. Also did you tried what I wrote earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I think that's your problem. You're using the "JSON-Simple" library (`org.json.simple.*`) instead of the "JSON for Java" library (`org.json.*`). They both have classes named `JSONArray`. But the `org.json.simple.JSONArray` from JSON-Simple does not return JSON from its `toString()` method like the `org.json.JSONArray` from "JSON for Java" does.

You need to use `toJSONString()` instead on your `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` objects.

Pay close attention to which libraries you're actually using. Including them (preferably with version numbers) in your questions will make answering questions like this easier. Class names are not unique across projects.

Comment: He should just use one Json library. Gson have a `JsonArray` class. And this `BinaryPojo` is not useful.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a design question. This is the reason OP's particular code was giving them that error, and answers the question as framed. That it kept so many people busy for a dozen comments at least makes it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Make changes as below and try.

```
public class BinaryPojo {    
    public List<BinPojo> binary;
}
```

Read JSON data as below.

```
URL feedURL = new URL("your_json_feed_url_here");  

Gson gson = new Gson();

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(feedURL.openStream());

BinaryPojo binaryPojo = gson.fromJson(reader, BinaryPojo.class);
List<BinPojo> binPojo = binaryPojo.binary;

for (BinPojo result : binPojo) {
    System.out.println("attributeIndex: " + result.attributeIndex);
    System.out.println("attributeValue: " + result.attributeValue);
    System.out.println("binaryValue: " + result.binaryValue);
}
```

Get the Gson library from [Gson official site](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)